# Drop Down Control in Android other that Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using `spinner` and looking for other similar control in `Eclipse`, I need to change drop down view of `spinner`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> Timeadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TimeIntervals);
```

For this I have used `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` but it change whole `spinner` view with a radio button in front

```
ArrayAdapter<String> Timeadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, TimeIntervals);
```

But output view I am looking for is not there.

Please help,

Comment: You can use `Dialog` read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this mihgt help you [Multi Selection Dialog](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/) and this might be helpful too [Single Selection Dialog](http://phaniraghav.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/android-dialog-listview-for-single-selection/) anyway you can always get help from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), I hope this is useful to you